# Textviews inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have 2 textview inside a layout. The layout will be used in recyclerview.

First the layout is like this:

[image: layout]

and my code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mViewRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result become clipped like this. It seems like the margin right is not functioning.

[image: result]

I've also tried making the width of textviews become 0dp.

[image]

The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mViewRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result become like below. The textview below doesn't match the constraint above it.

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: try to change constraintVertical_bias value

Comment: @BapusahebShinde just tried it for second textview. not working

Comment: try to add constraint between two textview

Comment: @charlie I tried your code (code with layout_width = 0) and it is working as expected. textview2 is not overlapping with textview1

Comment: @charlie I have used  'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2' in build.gradle.

Comment: @ZohraKhan I'm also using version 1.0.2. Maybe it's different because I set the value from activity and use it inside recyclerview?

Comment: @ZohraKhan I tested it in emulator android version 8.0

Comment: @charlie Try it on device. I tried it on my phone and it is working.

Comment: @ZohraKhan yes i tried it. it worked. but wondering why not working in emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Output]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mViewRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="asd;fjalksd fjlkasdjflasdflkasdlfkja lsdkfjals dfalskdfj alsdkfja sdlfkjalsdfj"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mTextViewDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="date asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfasdf"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/mTextViewTitle"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mTextViewTitle"  />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: same code as mine? It works in editor. But when test it in emulator it overlaps

Comment: have you check in real device ?

Comment: thanks. tried it in real device and it worked. But why does the emulator behave differently?